# Group by string occurence using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, parsing, group-by

Googling brought up nothing helpful, so I'm asking here: How to group a string by occurence of a certain string?

**Example data of a petting zoo**

```
Name:            My little petting zoo        CRLF
Owner:           Atrotygma                    CRLF
AverageVisitors: 100                          CRLF
PricePerTicket:  5                            CRLF
ZooSize:         20                           CRLF
Animal:          Goat                         CRLF
Age:             5                            CRLF
FavoriteFood:    Grass                        CRLF
Animal:          Sheep                        CRLF
Age:             3                            CRLF
Legs:            2 ( + 2 wheels)              CRLF
Animal:          Dire Wolf                    CRLF
Name:            Puppy                        CRLF
Size:            20                           CRLF
Age:             10.000                       CRLF
Classification:  Still alive                  CRLF
```

Goal: Animals should be grouped together (indicator: Animal) where each animal is followed by its (random, unpredictable) attributes (until the next animal).

```
Name:            My little petting zoo        
Owner:           Atrotygma                    
AverageVisitors: 100                          
PricePerTicket:  5                            
ZooSize:         20                           
Animal:          Key: Goat                         
    Age:             5                            
    FavoriteFood:    Grass                        
Animal:          Key: Sheep                        
    Age:             3                            
    Legs:            2 ( + 2 wheels)              
Animal:          Key: Dire Wolf                    
    Name:            Puppy                        
    Size:            20                           
    Age:             10.000                       
    Classification:  Still alive
```

I know this is a horrible form of data, but it's not mine and I can't change anything at it.

Comment: Step 1: Create an object structure. Step 2: Parse the original string into the object structure. Step 3: Group the object structure. Step 4: Output the object structure into the desired format.

Comment: How is the data presented to you? Filestream? Plain old string?

Comment: How do you know when the Animal properties stop, when it gets to the next Animal? Is there any data after the last animal? Can other data exist in between animals?

Comment: @SimonBelanger Multiline string as above, each line separated by CRLF.

Comment: @musefan The only indicator is the next animal. If I see the word "animal", a new group should start until the next occurence of "animal" and so on until no data is left. 'Can other data exist [...]?': No, as soon as the first animal occured, the following data is only animal related.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth This is not helpful as I can only assume the 'object structure'. All animal attributes are completely unpredictable (hell, there could be even zoo information without a single animal, animals without any attributes or only animals, without zoo information).

Comment: @Atrotygma: My advice certainly is helpful. What prevents you from creating an `Animal` class that is basically a named dictionary, with the name being the name of the animal and the dictionary being the attributes? Parse the string into a list of this `Animal` class and your task will suddenly be oh so simple.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth "Parse the string into a list of this Animal class" - there problems already starts. What you just said to me: If you want to go to the moon, just build a rocket. How hard could this be anyway?

Comment: @Atrotygma: I showed you a way how to break down the problem into smaller, manageable pieces. And I know that this doesn't solve your problem, that's why I posted it as a *comment*. It does however help you solve your own problem. Have you even tried following the steps I outlined? And parsing a structured string certainly isn't rocket science...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I am fully aware about how the steps that you suggested are being done. My problem is indeed the parsing as parsing is only not rocket science when it's done lousy. During my whole time as a programmer, I saw so many parsers and protocol clients that crash completely if you send them just a simple wrong character, so it's a concern to me to do it right and safe. And instead of parsing everything 'by hand', I asked if there's a LINQ ext. to group by a certain string so half of my work would be done if there is.

Comment: @Atrotygma: But your problem is not about grouping and LINQ isn't a solution for everything. You have a single string. You *need* to parse it somehow before you can use LINQ to group it.

Comment: Perhaps split the string by colon and then load each 2 values into a dictionary. Then iterate the dictionary and do whatever you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Split` on "Animal:" to break up the string. Then you can do what you like with the resulting set of animal strings.

Comment: Then I will get something like this: [...PricePerTicket: 5 CRLF ZooSize:         20 CRLF], [Goat CRLF Age: 5 CRLF...]. But what if there isn't any zoo information inside the message? I can't assume that the first key from the resulting array is about the zoo, and I can't assume that every zoo information starts with "Name"..

Comment: ...how would you, as a human reading the string, know which section is about the Zoo?

Answer (score 0):

This will make you display your string with the desired format.First i make a list of your string(with proper split option),the get the indexes of the "Animal" word occurence,after that(and this is of the top of my head,maybe the long way lol),make a temp list with the strings between the aninal string  and loop through the original list modifying those specific strings:

```
List<string> words = str.Split(new char[]{'\r','\n'},
                                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
int[] indexes = words.Select((b, i) => b.StartsWith("Animal") ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToArray();
List<string> temp = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
{
      if (i == indexes.Length - 1)
         temp.AddRange(words.GetRange(indexes[i] + 1, words.Count - (indexes[i] + 1)));
      else
         temp.AddRange(words.GetRange(indexes[i] + 1, indexes[i + 1] - (indexes[i] + 1)));
}

for (int y = 0; y < words.Count; y++)
{
     if (temp.Contains(words[y]))
        words[y] = "\t" + words[y];
}
```

After this long journey your words list will have the desired format.

EDIT:
The short way:

```
List<string> words = str.Split(new char[]{'\r','\n'},
                                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
int[] indexes = words.Select((b, i) => b.StartsWith("Animal") ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == indexes.Length - 1)
        words = words.Select(s => words.GetRange(indexes[i] + 1, words.Count - (indexes[i] + 1)).Contains(s) ? s = "\t" + s : s).ToList();
    else
        words = words.Select(s => words.GetRange(indexes[i] + 1, indexes[i + 1] - (indexes[i] + 1)).Contains(s) ? s = "\t" + s : s).ToList();
}
```

Still some optimizations to go......